# How to press Ctrl+V in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, keypress

In one of my automated tests I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in text box to paste text in it. But I can't do that. I'm using Selenium WebDriver for .net v. 2.35.0.0. 
Here is my code, it does not work. It presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then <kbd>V</kbd>, but text not gets pasted in the box:

```
IWebDriver webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"C:\Users\us\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SeleniumTests\SeleniumTests\test.html");
            var el = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='fld']"));
            el.Click();
            Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver);
            builder.KeyDown(el, Keys.LeftControl).Perform();
            builder.SendKeys(el, "v").Perform();
            builder.KeyUp(el, Keys.LeftControl).Perform();

            webDriver.Quit();
```

**Update:**
OS: Windows Server 2012, x64
Browser: IE10

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure there's something in your clipboard?

Comment: yes, I selected text before running this code.

Comment: What OS/Browser have you used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what I would suggest:

```
IWebDriver webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"C:\Users\us\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SeleniumTests\SeleniumTests\test.html");
var el = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='fld']"));
el.Click();
el.SendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+ "v");

webDriver.Quit();
```

Comment: it worked. thanks! Strange though: I tried this before posting this question and it didn't work for me :) Maybe I missed something because I checked lots of different approaches. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Vitaliy: It might be because you used a capital "V". For some reason capital letters don't work.

Comment: I think, Ctrl + capital 'V' doesn't work, because 'V' = Shift + 'v' in webdriver, and total sequence is: Ctrl + Shift + v

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me, what worked for me was:

```
new Actions(driver).KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control).SendKeys("v").KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control).Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple way

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(FileUpDownLoad._SOURCE_NAME)).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "v");
```