# Paste clipboard to website in python to a textbox

Tags: python

I need in python to paste text that i have in the buffer(ctrl+v) to a web site that I open right into the text box open website with:

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https//..")
    item = driver.find_element_by_name('text')
    item.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "v")
```

i have python 2.7.13

when opening web from cmd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):      #driver.get("https://bitbucket.wdc.com/plugins/servlet/ssh/account/keys/add")
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
        self.service.start()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
        os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: "python 2.13" doesn't seem to exist. [Python 2.7.13 does, though](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2713/). Also, what have you written in order to solve this? Where exactly are you facing issues?

Comment: [How to press Ctrl+V in Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322883/how-to-press-ctrlv-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with clipboard - it can't find `geckodriver.exe` which you need to get access to Firefox - see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/

Comment: [Setting path to firefox binary on windows with selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713824/setting-path-to-firefox-binary-on-windows-with-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can send `Ctrl+V` and it will paste text from clipboard

```
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://google.com')

item = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
item.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "v")
```

---

**EDIT:** I found some page with `<textarea>` and it works for me with `<textarea>` too.

Because `<textarea>` is inside `<iframe>` so I have to switch frame.

```
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea')

frame = driver.find_element_by_id('iframeResult')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

item = driver.find_element_by_id('w3mission')
item.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "v")
```

---

You can also try to use [paperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) to get text from clipboard and put it as normal text

```
import pyperclip

#pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')

text = pyperclip.paste()
#print(text)

import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea')

frame = driver.find_element_by_id('iframeResult')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

item = driver.find_element_by_id('w3mission')
item.clear()
item.send_keys(text)
```

Comment: This is my html message box:
<textarea class="textarea long-field monospace" name="text" id="text" rows="12" autofocus="" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
I use item = driver.find_element_by_name('text') it dosent work :/

Comment: do you get any error message? Better show URL to this page in question. You can also try [paperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) to get text from clipboard to variable and put it in textarea as any other text from variable.

Comment: I found some page with textarea and it works for me with textarea.

Comment: I thinks the error is when opening the web

Comment: if you have error then always put full error in question - it is always very important information.